# Best way to instantiate a type parameter class in Scala

Tags: list, scala, instantiation, typeclass, empty-list

I wanted to have a Queue class that could be used the same way as a list.

For instance,

```
val q = Queue()
```

would instantiate an empty queue.

For that purpose I tried using a companion class :

```
object Queue {
    def apply() = new Queue[Any]
}
```

Is that the right way to do it ?

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by "could be used the same way as a list"? Just being able to be create one without `new`? Or some other operations?

Comment: I mean using it without new, but I'm not sure my way is the right one.
Isn't `Any` a hack ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `apply` method of the companion object is the right way to do it, but you could also add a type parameter on `apply` itself:

```
object Queue {
    def apply[T]() = new Queue[T]
}
```

So that you can create a `Queue` of the right type:

```
val q = Queue[Int]()
```

Usually you also allow populating the sequence on creation, so that the element type can be inferred, as in:

```
def apply[T](elms: T*) = ???
```

So that you can do:

```
val q = Queue(1,2,3) // q is a Queue[Int]
```

Comment: Isn't there any way for me to do q = Queue() and let it infer the type with the following lines ? (As for a List)

Comment: @Sheeft that isn't possible, even for a list. You can do `val q: List[Int] = List()`, or `val q = List[Int]()`, but `val q = List()` will create a `List[Nothing]`, whatever you use is for later on.

Comment: Ok thanks. So my use of `Any` was indeed a hack. I get it I should make my SynchronizedQueue covariant for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

If you want to initialise an object without using `new`, then using `apply()` as a factory method in the companion is absolutely the right way to go about it.

You might also want to consider a more specific factory (or factories) to help make your code more self-documenting.

```
object Queue {
  def apply[T](xs: T*) = new Queue(xs: _*)
  def empty[T] = new Queue[T]()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But your empty definition raised two errors : _error: not found: type T_ and _error: not found: type empty_

Comment: Heh, yes. I should have turned it to a `def` when I added the type param. Now fixed